# Adding AppleScript/osascript to PATH

Tags: python, zsh, zshrc, osascript

Very noob question, but couldn't find a decent answer.

Working with a command line plugin that requires adding AppleScript to my path, but honestly not sure what the right format is.

I know where the script is on my system.

```
$ which osascript

/usr/bin/osascript
```

But I'm not sure if this is how I would export it to my Path.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is correct.

Also, it's likely that /usr/bin is already in $PATH by default; that's how it is on most Unix systems, including Macs.